# comment from facebook api with the graph api with objective - c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get comments of a facebook post with the graph api. Now I have the following method.

```
+(NSArray *)getCommentsWithParam:(NSString *)Param
{
    NSString *request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=%@",Param];
    NSLog(@"request is %@",request);
    NSString *vfk = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comments.data"];
    return [[self executeGenkFetch:request] valueForKey:vfk];
}
```

`executeGenkFetch` is just gonna parse the json and gives me back an `NSDictionary` with the results. But now when I read this results like this.

```
-(void)getComments{
    NSArray *comments           = [GenkData getCommentsWithParam:_commentsUrl];
    NSLog(@"Comments are %@", comments);
}
```

I always get (null). This is how the json looks like.

```
{
   "http://www.krcgenk.be//nl/nieuws/show/krc-genk-speelt-1-1-gelijk-op-vfb-stuttgart/1329": {
      "comments": {
         "data": [
            {
               "id": "412008348889230_2723627",
               "from": {
                  "name": "Put Patrick",
                  "id": "1090951059"
               },
               "message": "Proficiat mannen",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-02-15T00:10:12+0000",
               "like_count": 4,
               "user_likes": false
            },
            {
               "id": "412008348889230_2723878",
               "from": {
                  "name": "Benny Froyen",
                  "id": "1095529244"
               },
               "message": "Knap resultaat voor Genk. Alles blijft open voor de terugwedstrijd in Genk. Leuk!",
               "can_remove": false,
               "created_time": "2013-02-15T02:25:51+0000",
               "like_count": 1,
               "user_likes": false
            }
 ],
         "paging": {
            "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/412008348889230/comments?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=412008348889230_2725492"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you got to getComments from executeGenkFetch? Is there any delegate methods of GenkData that you need to implement? Is that json an output example or is that your current output?